# yii showing data on cgridview from others table

Tags: yii, foreign-keys, cgridview

I'm having problem to show data on cgridview using foreign keys.
This is my case, i have table employee(id, username), client(id, username), and transaction(id, employeeId, clientId). employeeId foreign key to employee.id, and clientId is foreign key to client.id. Now, I want to show employee's name and client's name instead of their id on transaction admin.php.
This is my code:

```
class Transaction extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $client_search;
    public $employee_search;

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        .
        .
        .
        array('id, employeeId, clientId, balance, status, date, client_search, employee_search', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'employee' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Employee', 'employeeId'),
        'client' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Client', 'clientId'),
    );
}

public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with = array( 'client', 'employee' );

    $criteria->together = true;
    $criteria->compare('t.id',$this->id,true);
    $criteria->compare('employee.username', $this->employee_search, true );
    $criteria->compare('client.username', $this->client_search, true );
    $criteria->compare('t.balance',$this->balance,true);
    $criteria->compare('t.status',$this->status);
    $criteria->compare('t.date',$this->date,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}

 //the other functions are there, i don't edit it.
}
```

that is my model/Transaction.php

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'transaction-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    array(
        'header' => 'Employee',
        'name' => 'employee_search',
        'value' => '$data->employee->username',
    ),
    array(
        'header' => 'Client',
        'name' => 'client_search',
        'value' => '$data->client->username',
    ),
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
));
```

that is my views/transaction/admin.php.
and this code gave me error Trying to get property of non-object ($data->employee->id   marked).
Actually I have succed to show the employee's name instead of employee's id, but, after that I use the same method for the client, and the error appear.
anyone can help me? My method is making public employee_search, add the rules, add the relation, adding $creiteria->with, then change the admin.php. Anyone please help me.

//UPDATE
SOLVED. Its actually my fault. There is an error in the database about the relation (foreign key). My coding is fine.

Comment: Add as much code as you can. The controller (where you feed your view variable `$model`), for instance would probably help us out.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess without being able to debug your code but here are some things that could help (I'll add more as I can think of them).

It might be because both the default `joinType` for relations is `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and maybe you have a `Transaction` where one of them is null? If you try to access attributes on null object (as opposed to an actual `ActiveRecord` object), that's precisely the error message you would be seeing.

You could change it by doing:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'employee' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Employee', 'employeeId',array('joinType'=>'INNER JOIN')),
        'client' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Client', 'clientId',array('joinType'=>'INNER JOIN')),
    );
}
```

**P.S.:** `INNER JOIN` is the same as just `JOIN`

Not sure if it will help you, but it's worth trying.

More information at: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail

Comment: Sorry, it's actually my fault. There is an error in the database. My coding is fine. Thank you anyway to help.